# Counter does not working in expected way in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have created a `projet` scaffold that has many to one association with `user`. project scaffold has one to many association with `stage`, stage has one to many association with `sub_task`. each scaffold has one attribute `planned_end_date` now i want to print number of stage, stage and sub_task is not completed on selected date. and print that into column of project#index action. this code works good in project#show action by removing `@projects.each do |project|` but same code in project#index action prints same number in each row of column.

projects_controller.rb(index#Action)

```
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)

    @projects.each do |project|

      @stages = Stage.where(project_id: @projects.ids )

      @tasks = Task.where(stage_id: @stages.ids)
      @sub_tasks = SubTask.where(task_id: @tasks.ids)

      stage_counter = 0
      task_counter = 0
      sub_task_counter = 0

      @stages.each{|s| stage_counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 0 || s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 2}
      @tasks.each{|s| task_counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 0 || s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 2}
      @sub_tasks.each{|s| sub_task_counter += 1 if s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 0 || s.planned_end_date.past? && s.status == 2}


      @count = stage_counter + task_counter + sub_task_counter
        end
```

project#index

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Project Name</th>
        <th>Activity Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= project.project_name %></td>
          <td><%= @count %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.4'
```

i want to print total number of stage, task ,sub_tasks of each project that not completed on time. in project#index action. Can anyone knows what i am missing???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rock, first of all, you are not using ruby properly.

you don't need to use loop and counters instead, you can do like:

```
@projects = current_user.projects.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)

@total_count = []

@projects.each do |project|

  stages = project.stages.where('stages.planned_end_date < ?', Time.now).where('status IN (?)', [0,2])

  tasks = project.tasks.where('tasks.planned_end_date < ?', Time.now).where('status IN (?)', [0,2])

  sub_tasks = project.sub_tasks.where('sub_tasks.planned_end_date < ?', Time.now).where('status IN (?)', [0,2])

  @total_count << { project_id: (stages.count + tasks.count + sub_tasks.count) }
end
```

## output will be:

[{1: 20}, {2: 25}, {4: 30}, {7: 10}]
This is an array of the hash in which each element has key as project ID and value as a total of stages, tasks, and subtasks of that project

Comment: no, still gets printed first project ```@total_count```to all other projects.

Comment: ok so use @total_count += instead of only = if you want grand total of all projects' data. Also first declare the \@total_count = 0 before the loop.

Comment: got error on using += ```undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: Has mentioned already, please initialize @total_count =0 before the loop

Comment: no still first count gets printed to all projects coulmn

Comment: there are many projects and each project has their own stage, task and sub_tasks. and i want in project#index action to print their corresponding count.

Comment: so if you want a separate count of all projects then use array. initialize total_count = [ ], then in loop do total_count << \@stages.count + \@tasks.count + s\@ub_tasks.count

Comment: i think @total_count is also biased it does not appears to be count of first project. could  you post your updated answer?

Comment: what your code does is, it only respond stage array even after adding ```@tasks``` and ```@sub_tasks```

Comment: sure.. let me do it for you

Comment: still error - ``` undefined method `tasks' for #<Project:0x00007fb0d4409db8>```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209143/discussion-between-vishal-and-rock).